# Killing threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I've created a class which is an extension of Thread.  This class hits a web service and throws some data on screen.  I don't care about persisting this data (the screen displays search results).

Currently, the user simply types into an EditText and clicks a search button.  I'd like to take away the search button and implement something similar to Google's Instant Search where, as you type, the search results get updated.

This means, as the user types, the search parameters change.  **I want to be able to kill the currently running thread (if one is currently running) and spawn a new one with the new search string**.  How can this be achieved?  Can I do it with Thread or will I need to use a new object?

Comment: This is not something that should happen in a mobile device. Presumably you're on 3g and not wifi and it could take a LONG time for even 1 search result. You'd have to cache the search results of every possible combination the user could type. This is insane. Depending the data, you'd probably want to just get all the data at once on start up, and then search through it locally using autocomplete like mentioned below. If your data is webpages, don't even think about it.

Comment: The data being searched for a list a list of words.  It returns, at most, 25 words. When you type 'w' the web service asks for words that begin with 'w'.  If you then type 'wi' the web service asks for words that begin with 'wi'.  What I would like to accomplish is, if the web service call for 'w' is still active when the user types 'i', it cancels it and attempts the web service call for 'wi'.  Additionally, I've placed a sleep of 2 seconds before the web service is called; so if the user types 'w' and then 'wi' within 2 seconds, no bandwidth was used because the first call never got out.

Comment: The web service calls happen in threads; so by stopping the web service call I actually mean stopping the thread containing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more difficult than simply killing a thread. You can call interrupt() on the thread, but the thread will have to check its interrupt status periodically and self-terminate.

Secondly, you will not want to start a thread immediately on a user typing. You will quickly overwhelm the system with thread spawning. Implement a wait period of 100-200 milliseconds before doing the search so that you can be reasonably sure the user is done typing. Google's server can handle the load, but the handset won't be able to.

EDIT: to expand on my first point, threads can be difficult to cancel. In this case the event dispatch thread will need to somehow tell the running thread it needs to stop. You can use the `interrupt` facility built into threads, but it tends to be touchy as pointed out by [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/03/02/cancelling-tasks-threadinterrupt-fragility). Instead, I would simply have a `boolean` variable that can be set to `cancelled` by some outside thread. The trick (like shown in that link) will be that you will need to periodically check if the thread has been cancelled, and if so you will need to manually abort.

The next problem you will run into is if a web call has already been made to some outside server. It will block in that thread until it comes back and the thread will not be able to kill itself. This could take several seconds.

So let's play this out - what if a user types a character, and your timeout period expires for whatever reason and a web call is made, then the user types another character where the timeout period expires so another web call is made? If your web calls take 5 seconds, then the first thread will continue to run, even if the event dispatch thread cancels it, for at least 5 seconds. You now have two threads making web calls.

Now expand that. What if a user does this and makes 4 or 5 threads? This is where you overwhelm the resources of your handset. I am not telling you not to pursue this, just trying to point out the potential problems that come with the territory.

Comment: Well what I was planning on doing is, when the user types a character, any executing thread is cancelled, search results are wiped and a new thread with the new search parameter is launched.  When a thread is launched, it waits for 2-3 seconds before actually hitting the webservice.  This gives the user time to type another character and cancel the previous search before it used the radio.  The problem is that I don't programmatically know how to do this (the cancel part).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `AutoCompleteTextView` widget.  prefetch your search hints from your web service to load them into the autocomplete array and set its adapter. optionally use a custom cursor adapter depending on how complex your hints are.

something like:

```
AutoCompleteTextView inputSearch;
String[] autocompleteArray = new String[size of prefetched items];
//fill autocompleteArray with webservice data

inputSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
searchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.autcomplete_dropdown, autocompleteArray);
inputSearch.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
```

`R.layout.autocomplete_dropdown` could look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:singleLine="false"
  android:textSize="15sp"
  android:paddingLeft="3dip"
  android:paddingRight="3dip"
  android:paddingTop="15dip"
  android:paddingBottom="15dip"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

do your searching in the app, how large is the content you will be searching? pre-load all the data in sqlite and check for updated data from the web every so often perhaps?

otherwise i'd say you should limit the amount of times your app tries to start a thread.  setup some sort of timer that will: 
see if...

1. a thread is already working
2. the input has changed since the last
   time or has a non-empty search value
3. the user is even on the search
   screen

if everything is OK, start up a thread to get results

just a thought, haven't tried this

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not have made my intentions clear.  I'm not looking to re-create Google's auto-complete functionality.  I'm looking to re-create Google's Instant Search.  As the user types a search word in the EditText, the results in the list update.

Answer (score 0):

Thread creating is very consuming operation. Thus I would recommend have one thread which will subsequently call webservices with new search strings.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is **Auto Complete**. I don't think you need to start a couple of threads to handle that. Work with android [Auto Complete](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) and use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Furthermore it is not recommended to use threads by subclassing java thread or implementing the interface. You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform time consuming operations in the background.

Comment: No, I do not mean Auto Complete.  What I meant was Instant Search.  As the user types in the EditText, the search results displayed in the list update.  I will look into using AsyncTask instead of Thread, though whatever type of asynchronous operation allows me to do what I want is what I'll need to use.